# Spring boot - 2 JNDI configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jndi

[image]

Posted my current configuration

Comment: I have removed batch-file tag. I am using boot- 1.5.2.RELEASE version

Answer (score 1):

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Value("${spring.datasource.primary.jndi-name}")
    private String primaryJndiName;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.secondary.jndi-name}")
    private String secondaryJndiName;

    @Primary
    @Bean(destroyMethod = "") // destroy method is disabled for Weblogic update app ability
    public DataSource primaryDs() {
        JndiDataSourceLookup lookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        return lookup.getDataSource(primaryJndiName);
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "") // destroy method is disabled for Weblogic update app ability
    public DataSource secondaryDs() {
        JndiDataSourceLookup lookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        return lookup.getDataSource(secondaryJndiName);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this way and it is working

you can put your jndi values in one properties file and then load that property file in your bean defination.xml

jndi.properties

```
#JNDI property for job repository
job.repository.db.connection=jdbc/pgDB
#JNDI property for application
application.db.connection=jdbc/db2Conn
```

Bean-defination.xml

```
<bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath*:/properties/jndi.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
    </bean>

<bean id="jobRepoDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="${job.repository.db.connection}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="${application.db.connection}" />
    </bean>
```